# create a custom chrome browser for android

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser

Is there a way to create a custom browser with all the basic functionality and looks of the current chrome browser for android ? preferably in android studio or eclipse

Comment: Better to search on _Google_ or ask to _Google_.

Comment: I already googled the f out of it, couldn't find anything useful ...

Answer (score 0):

The mobile chrome browser is open source based on chromium, similar to how the chromium browser is opensource on the desktop. So yes it should be possible.